# Read the first Json Element in a Pythonscript

Tags: python, json

i need the first json object´s name (here in this examole its "object") as a String. The Json looks like this:
`{'object':{'a': ['123', '234', '345'], 'b' : '1234'}}`
but the objects name switches randomly with the user input. So I need to read the first element of the Json file like list[0] with lists.

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? Actually, hold on. Why exactly do you "need" the "first" entry in the object - and what does that actually *mean*? You understand that conceptually, the key-value pairs in an object *don't have a meaningful order, right*? That's a fundamental part of the concept.

Comment: It could be a need, definitely. Consider an API that gives a JSON response, which will have the same order for every request, even if it's meaningless. e.g. an API that gives research paper links/metrics on a subject, like covid-19, we could see if the first paper was different, implying a new paper was published since the last request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a JSON string `data`

```
import json    
jsondict = json.loads(data)
first = list(jsondict)[0]
```

This will give you the first object's name.